# Decimalformat is not working for 3 digit number in java

Tags: java

The below code is working fine for the number 3.5E7, if I changed the number to 305.22 or any 3 digit number, the output will be starting with "00". Eg 00305.20 like this. How to display the result in the normal format for 3 digit number using decimalformat. Below is my code

```
double number = 305.22;
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#00000.00");
String formattedNumber = format.format(number);
```

Comment: Did you try `"####0.00"`?

Comment: Could you please tell us, with various example inputs and outputs, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: Its working now, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)! It tells you all you need to know about `DecimalFormat`!

In the docs, it says that the `#` character means:

> Digit, zero shows as absent

Translating that to more understandable terms,

> Show the digit here if the digit in this position is not 0, otherwise show nothing.

So if you don't want those  preceding `0`s, you should use this format:

```
#####0.00
```

The first `0` is still needed because you still want to show a `0` before the decimal point if the number is something like `0.5`. (Or maybe you don't, in which case replace the `0` with a `#`)